# How to select LI except first and second?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the structure of the content, I want to select all LI except the first two (ie no-link)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var nosubnav = jQuery('.first-level li:not(:has(ul))');
  var nosubnavsize = jQuery('.first-level li:not(:has(ul))').size();
  jQuery(nosubnav).css('border' , '1px solid red');
  alert('List item which does not have submenu  '+nosubnavsize);

});
```

---

```
div class="navigation-container">
    <ul class="first-level">
    <li><a href="#">No Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">No Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2.2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.2.1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
```

related Question : [How to count li which does not have ul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771801/how-to-count-li-which-does-not-have-ul)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("ul.first-level > li:gt(1)").hide()
```

I'm assuming you're talking about the LIs which are on the **top** level, i.e. direct descendants of `.first-level`. Otherwise, you can omit the parent child selector (`>`).

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
li + li + li, ul ul li
```

i.e. An item that is next to an item that is next to an item, or an item that is inside a list which is inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the first two li´s a css-class (e.g. "noLink") and use

```
$("li:not('.noLink')").hide(); //or whatever
```